# Get data from mysql database inside for loop with php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I have this php code - for loop and on every step , every increment search for data in mysql table `aktivnosti`

PHP:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=30; $i++;){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['ID'] = $i;

// ATTEMP TO GET DATA FROM aktivnosti WHERE id_activity = $i

    $rs1 = $db->prepare('SELECT naziv FROM aktivnosti WHERE id_activity=:idd');
          $rs1->bindParam(':idd', $i); 

          $rs1->execute();
          $naz = $rs1->fetchColumn();

          $temp['activity'] =  '<button>'.$naz.'</button>';



    $output['data'][] = $temp;

}
$jsonTable = json_encode($output);
```

So as you can see from code above I try to get data on every `$i` increment and search if `id_activity on table aktivnosti = $i`

I get just one result so I get just first `'naziv'`, I need to get all `naziv` data from table aktivnosti where id_activity = $i and create:

```
<button>$naz[0]<button>
<button>$naz[1]<button>
<button>$naz[2]<button>
<button>$naz[how many times id_activity = $i]<button>
```

How I can do that? Some ideas?

sorry for my engish. Thanks

Comment: why not just get all the rows you need and then loop through the results?  instead of hitting the database 30 times?

Comment: The query prepare should go out of (before) the for loop.

Comment: becouse I need to create a JSON that have 30 rows 30 IDS...

Comment: You're making 30 database requests instead of one? What if someone deletes an activity? Your code stops working then.

Comment: the for loop is 30 times becouse in database I have stored days in month, so I dont know in which day i have activity so I create loop to go trought mysql table aktivnosti and catch data...

Comment: I can have 3 activity on day 15, also I can have 0 (zero) activity on day - 15. - and for every activity 15.day I need to create <button> ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments above, you are taking a bad approach here. You should be able to get all this data in a single query.  You probably also need to take a look at your schema if you want to have the concept of a fixed number of 30 days with each days related to `n` number of records.  I would suggest two tables

day_list

```
day_id  day_name (or any other day-related data fields)
1       ...
2       ...
...     ...
30      ...
```

days_records

```
record_id   day_id   other_data
1           1        ...
2           1        ...
3           3        ...
4           5        ...
...
```

You would then query this like:

```
SELECT
    d.day_id AS day_id
    dr.record_id AS record_id
    dr.other_date AS other_data
FROM day_list AS d
LEFT JOIN day_records AS dr
    ON d.day_id = dr.day_id
```

Sorry for the change in table names, as don't know what your database schema represents in real-world terms.

You then make a single query like:

```
$query = <<<EOT
SELECT
    d.day_id AS day_id
    dr.record_id AS record_id
    dr.other_date AS other_data
FROM day_list AS d
LEFT JOIN day_records AS dr
    ON d.day_id = dr.day_id
EOT;

$rs1 = $db->execute($query);
if (false === $rs1) {
   // something went wrong. perhaps log an error
} else {
   while($row = $rs1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $temp = $row;
        // check to see if this date has a record
        if (empty($temp['record_id'])) {
            // this is a day with no associated record.
            // do something
        }
        // not shown - continue to manipulate your $temp as desired
        // then add to output array
        $output['data'][] = $temp
   }
}
```

Comment: Mike, I need to create a some kin of vertical calendar... SO the first column is date (days in month 1-30) and second column is activity, so for each day I need to search is there some activity or not, if not I create <button>Add activity</button> ... s its not answer for my problem

Comment: @JamesD. It is actually. In that the fact that you would LEFT JOIN your static list of days to the records themselves.  You would get NULL values for the items in date table where there is no record for that day. I will add example to my code.

Comment: ok, I will chech if data == NULL then I create html to show on that day

Comment: but while is the same as for loop... I need to create this: http://imgur.com/mXr3ax7 so its datatable with column with date and column with activity

Comment: check the answer, I update it, the while works like I use it in the above answer...

Comment: @JamesD. You will obviously need to change column names from my example.  I used English column names so I could explain the concept in general as I had no understanding of your existing DB schema.

Comment: I will try to do this, but what is that d. or dr. ? What that mean ? to stay as you write or...  ?

Comment: also how I can use range of dates and WHERE instead JOIN ?

Comment: you say "continue to manipulate your $temp as desired" - How I can do that?

Comment: @JamesD. Lots of questions here.  `d` and `dr` are just table aliases. The JOIN is important it is what gives you records in result set even if there are no items for the day.  Trying to get a day range would be as simple as adding a WHERE clause like `WHERE d.day_id BETWEEN ? AND ?`.  I just meant you can make any other changes to the `$temp` array that you may like add HTML wrappers and such.

Comment: Ok, this is database activity: http://i.imgur.com/B8aoedA.png Lets say that I need to create a period beetween 09.03.2014 and 12.03.2014. Timestamp_day is a column with values which I need to check ... so How I can with my table activity to create records, with period I post above and make a JSON that work for datatables.net plugin (json in that format)

Comment: @JamesD. I am not sure if we are even talking about the original question anymore. The original question had drastically different database object names (in some language other than English) and talked about having some value between 1-30 somehow representing a range of dates.  What you have just posted looks like something totally different.

Comment: Ok, I will post new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26761397/passing-through-a-period-of-time-and-finding-data-in-mysql-if-any

Comment: @Mike Brant please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763914/join-mysql-php-function-instead-foreach-loop I work half hour to put all code all tables into one question ? Can you integrate your code from this question on that Q ?

Comment: Mike please help me to integrate this code into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763914/join-mysql-php-function-instead-foreach-loop

Comment: @JamesD. In that question I am still honestly not sure what you are looking for.  At this point you have posted several different table schemas and show a desired table output that doesn;t list everyday, but then comment in response to answers that you need every day (even ones without activites) to be in your result set.  It really is not clear what you are asking. We are also not here to write your code for your. I have given you a strategy to create a table that has a record for every day that you can use to LEFT JOIN with the table that has you records. You don't seem to have attempted it.

Comment: I have a table activity so from that table I must get data if timestamp == thatday. I try with foreach $dateRangde as $date but somebody say that a bad idea becouse again I need to hit database with 30 queries...

Answer (score 1):

If you need both `ID` and `activity`:

```
$sql = <<<EOD
SELECT
    id_activity AS ID,
    CONCAT('<button>', naziv, '</button>') AS activity
FROM aktivnosti
WHERE id_activity BETWEEN 1 AND 30
ORDER BY id_activity
EOD;
$data = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$jsonTable = json_encode(compact('data'));
```

If you only use `activity`:

```
$sql = <<<EOD
SELECT CONCAT('<button>', naziv, '</button>')
FROM aktivnosti
WHERE id_activity BETWEEN 1 AND 30
ORDER BY id_activity
EOD;
$data = $db->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$jsonTable = json_encode(compact('data'));
```

Comment: Can you rewrite my code, becouse is not usefull when I put in my app

Comment: ...Do you really need `ID`?

Comment: So, use second snippet. You can get following json: `{"data":["<button>$naz[0]</button>","<button>$naz[1]</button>",...,"<button>$naz[29]</button>"]}`

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
 while($naz=$rs1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
```

{

```
echo $naz->column1;
echo $naz->column2;
```

}

instead of

```
 $naz = $rs1->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: i get this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/agroagro/public_html/template/tema/table1.php on line 45

Comment: $rs1 = $db->prepare('SELECT naziv FROM aktivnosti WHERE id_activity=:idd');
          $rs1->bindParam(':idd', $i); 
 
       $rs1->execute();
    while($naz=$rs1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $temp['vrsta'] =  '<button class="btn btn-danger">'.$naz.'</button>';
                  }
                       

    $output['data'][] = $temp;
    $i++;
}
$jsonTable = json_encode($output);

Comment: try this

 $rs1 = $db->prepare('SELECT naziv FROM aktivnosti WHERE id_activity=:idd');
 $rs1->bindParam(':idd', $i); 
 $rs1->execute(); 
 while($naz=$rs1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
  { 

  $temp['vrsta'] = '<button class="btn btn-danger">'.$naz.'</button>'; 
  }
   $output['data'][] = $temp; $i++;
  
   $jsonTable = json_encode($output);

Comment: i get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'catch' (T_CATCH) in /home/agroagro/public_html/template/tema/table1.php on line 43

Comment: $rs1 = $db->prepare('SELECT naziv FROM aktivnosti WHERE id_activity=:idd');
 $rs1->bindParam(':idd', $i); 
 $rs1->execute(); 
 while($naz=$rs1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
  { 

  $temp['vrsta'] = '<button class="btn btn-danger">'.$naz.'</button>'; 
  }
   $output['data'][] = $temp; $i++;
  
   $jsonTable = json_encode($output);